# VS 2015 unable to start iisexpress.exe - a componenent dll failed to load

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iis-express

Just installed Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise with Update 1. When I try to debug any application I receive this error:

- [iiserror.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfhyU.jpg)
- Unable to start program 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe'.
  A component dll failed to load. Try to restart this application. If failures continue, try disabling any installed add-ins or repair your installation.

IIS Express (v10) tray does not start, although i can start iisexpress manually (successfully). I still can't debug my application.

I can open the same project in visual studio 2013 and debugging runs fine (with iisexpress).

I have tried the following:

1. Running as administrator
2. Reinstalling iisexpress
3. Deleting iisexpress folder in c:\users*me*\documents\iisexpress
4. Repairing VS 2015
5. Reinstalling VS 2015

I am at a loss as to what it could be. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add the text of the error instead of linking to a screen shot. That way, the error message can be indexed and found by others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for future reference this was resolved by uninstalling VS 2015. Then I downloaded the new(er) VS 2015 with Update 1 already included as apposed to installing it (Update 1) separately after the VS 2015 installation.